# Why is "1" + + "1" = "11" but "1" - - "1" = 2 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operators, unary-operator

Today, I was made aware of an intriguing thing by my co-worker. Basically, he opened the console(Ctrl+shift+I) in the google chrome and typed the following:

```
"1" + + "1"
```

(please be aware of the spaces between the operators) 
This gave the result as `"11"` which is string and I totally understand it.

However, when the input is

```
"1" - - "1"
```

the console answered `2`.

Similarly I tried

```
"1" - - "4"
```

and console outputs `5`.

Also,

```
"1" - + "4"
```

gives the output `-3`.

I understand the logic but have no clue about the working of these operators.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what language? The rules vary significantly between JavaScript, PHP, Perl, and others. This could be a case of [wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat).

Comment: I guess JavaScript since it was on my google chrome's console, but I'm not very sure.

Comment: You can add strings, but you can't subtract strings, so Javascript converts them to numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `-` operator has no meanings on strings, so it converts the value to a `Number`.